# Find $n \in N$, for which $a+b+c+d = n \sqrt{(abcd)}$ has a solution $(a, b, c, d)$ in natural numbers.

Tags: number-theory, vieta-jumping

By pure logical observations, I got that $n=1,2,4$ satisfies but I couldn't get the proper theoretical proof. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The case $n=3$ is possible when $(a,b,c,d)=(25,2,2,1)$.

Comment: Oh, yeah thanks, but can you find all n?

Comment: @DietrichBurde  The cases $n=1,2,4$ can be dealt by setting $a=b=c=d$.  I have a feeling that there are solutions for every positive integer $n$, but I don't even have an example when $n=5$ yet.

Answer (score 2):

I generalized to 
$$  (w+x+y+z)^2 = k wxyz   $$
A solution [is "fundamental" in the sense of Hurwitz](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hurwitz_A_1907.pdf) if  we demand 
$$ w \geq x \geq y \geq z \geq 1  $$
and
$$  kxyz \geq 2(w+x+y+z) \; . \;   $$
Any solution for a certain value of $k$ descends to a fundamental by "Vieta Jumping." Thus, if there are no fundamental solutions for a given $k,$ there are no solutions at all.

ADDED: just as with the [tree of Markov Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_number), any of the fundamental solutions indicated below becomes the root of a tree of solutions. We move around within the tree by Vieta jumping, going in different directions depending on which number we choose to do the jumping. If we are jumping the entry called $w,$ the jumped value is
$$ w' = kxyz - 2x-2y-2z-w  $$
For example, with my $k=9,$ Batominovski's $(25,2,2,1)$
descends to
$$ (1,2,2,1) $$
since $9 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 -4-4-2 -25 = 36-10-25=1$

These are all I get:

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./mse
  k  1         w 4 x 4 y 4 z 4
  k  1         w 6 x 6 y 3 z 3
  k  1         w 8 x 5 y 5 z 2
  k  1         w 10 x 10 y 9 z 1
  k  1         w 12 x 6 y 4 z 2
  k  1         w 15 x 10 y 3 z 2
  k  1         w 18 x 9 y 8 z 1
  k  1         w 21 x 14 y 6 z 1
  k  1         w 30 x 24 y 5 z 1
  k  2         w 4 x 3 y 3 z 2
  k  2         w 8 x 4 y 2 z 2
  k  2         w 10 x 5 y 4 z 1
  k  2         w 12 x 8 y 3 z 1
  k  3         w 4 x 4 y 3 z 1
  k  3         w 6 x 2 y 2 z 2
  k  3         w 9 x 6 y 2 z 1
  k  4         w 2 x 2 y 2 z 2
  k  4         w 6 x 3 y 2 z 1
  k  5         w 5 x 2 y 2 z 1
  k  5         w 10 x 8 y 1 z 1
  k  6         w 6 x 4 y 1 z 1
  k  8         w 4 x 2 y 1 z 1
  k  9         w 2 x 2 y 1 z 1
  k  12         w 3 x 1 y 1 z 1
  k  16         w 1 x 1 y 1 z 1
Mon Oct 14 12:40:44 PDT 2019
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: What is the range of $k$ that you ran the search for?

Comment: @Batominovski I let $k$ go up to $56.$ I would say that your $k=25$ is impossible, and a careful proof need not be too difficult. The paper of Hurwitz is a long string of elementary observations.

Comment: So, it seems like the answer to the original problem is $n=1,2,3,4$.

Comment: @Batominovski I would say so. I don't see that taking square $k$ makes things easier. Given that this is yet another problem with no source or attribution, I think I will let it go.